# Advice precedence problem when one @Around advice does not proceed

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-aop

**Updated to rephrase question with additional information**

We have two annotations:

- `CustomLogging`
- `PollableStreamListener`

Both are implemented using aspects with Spring AOP.

`CustomLogging` annotation:

```java
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CustomLogging {

}
```

`CustomLoggingAspect` class:

```java
@Aspect
@Component
@Slf4j
@Order(value = 1)
public class CustomLoggingAspect {

  @Before("@annotation(customLogging)")
  public void addCustomLogging(CustomLogging customLogging) {
    log.info("Logging some information");
  }

}
```

`PollableStreamListener` annotation:

```java
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface PollableStreamListener {

}
```

`PollableStreamListenerAspect` class:

```java
@Aspect
@Component
@Slf4j
public class PollableStreamListenerAspect {

  private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

  private volatile boolean paused = false;

  @Around(value = "@annotation(pollableStreamListener) && args(dataCapsule,..)")
  public void receiveMessage(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint,
      PollableStreamListener pollableStreamListener, Object dataCapsule) {
    if (dataCapsule instanceof Message) {
      Message<?> message = (Message<?>) dataCapsule;
      AcknowledgmentCallback callback = StaticMessageHeaderAccessor
          .getAcknowledgmentCallback(message);
      callback.noAutoAck();

      if (!paused) {
        // The separate thread is not busy with a previous message, so process this message:
        Runnable runnable = () -> {
          try {
            paused = true;

            // Call method to process this Kafka message
            joinPoint.proceed();

            callback.acknowledge(Status.ACCEPT);
          } catch (Throwable e) {
            callback.acknowledge(Status.REJECT);
            throw new PollableStreamListenerException(e);
          } finally {
            paused = false;
          }
        };

        executor.submit(runnable);
      } else {
        // The separate thread is busy with a previous message, so re-queue this message for later:
        callback.acknowledge(Status.REQUEUE);
        log.info("Re-queue");
      }
    }
  }

}
```

We have a class called `CleanupController` which regularly executes according to a schedule.

`CleanupController` class:

```java
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${app.pollable-consumer.time-interval}")
  public void pollForDeletionRequest() {
    log.trace("Polling for new messages");
    cleanupInput.poll(cleanupSubmissionService::submitDeletion);
  }
```

When the schedule executes, it calls a method in another class that is annotated with both `PollableStreamListener` and `CustomLogging`. I've added a `Thread.sleep()` to imitate the method taking a while to execute.

```java
@PollableStreamListener
  @CustomLogging
  public void submitDeletion(Message<?> received) {
    try {
      log.info("Starting processing");
      Thread.sleep(10000);
      log.info("Finished processing");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.info("Error", e);
    }
  }
```

The problem I'm facing is that the output produced by `CustomLogging` is printed each time we poll for new messages using the `@Schedule`, but I only want it to print if the annotated method is actually executed (which may happen now, or may happen in the future depending on whether another message is currently being processed). This leads to confusing log messages because it implies that the message is being processed now when in fact it has been re-queued for future execution.

Is there some way that we can make these annotations work well together so that the `CustomLogging` output only happens if the annotated method executes?

---

**Update to use `@Order` on `PollableStreamListener`**

As per the suggestion of @dunni, I made the following changes to the original example above.

Set the order of 1 on the `PollableStreamListenerAspect`:

```java
@Aspect
@Component
@Slf4j
@Order(value = 1)
public class PollableStreamListenerAspect {
...
}
```

Increase the order to 2 for `CustomLoggingAspect`:

```java
@Aspect
@Component
@Slf4j
@Order(value = 2)
public class CustomLoggingAspect {
...
}
```

I found that after making these changes that the polling fails to detect new requests at all. It is the change on the `PollableStreamListenerAspect` that introduced this issue (I commented out that line and re-ran it, and things behaved as they did before).

---

**Update to use `@Order(value = Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)` on `PollableStreamListener`**

I've updated the `PollableStreamListener` to use the `HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE` and update the `@Around` value:

```java
@Aspect
@Component
@Slf4j
@Order(value = Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class PollableStreamListenerAspect {

  private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

  private volatile boolean paused = false;

  @Around(value = "@annotation(au.com.brolly.commons.stream.PollableStreamListener)")
  public void receiveMessage(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
    if (!paused) {
      // The separate thread is not busy with a previous message, so process this message:
      Runnable runnable = () -> {
        try {
          paused = true;

          // Call method to process this Kafka message
          joinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          throw new PollableStreamListenerException(e);
        } finally {
          paused = false;
        }
      };

      executor.submit(runnable);
    } else {
      // The separate thread is busy with a previous message, so re-queue this message for later:
      log.info("Re-queue");
    }
  }
}
```

This is partially working now. When I send a Kafka message, it gets processed, and the logging from the `CustomLogging` annotation only prints if another Kafka message isn't being processed. So far so good.

The next challenge is to get the `@Around` to accept the `Message` that is being provided via Kafka. I attempted this using the above example with the following lines changed:

```java
  @Around(value = "@annotation(au.com.brolly.commons.stream.PollableStreamListener) && args(dataCapsule,..)")
  public void receiveMessage(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, Object dataCapsule) {
...
}
```

The server starts correctly, but when I publish a Kafka message then I get the following exception:

```
2021-04-22 10:38:00,055 ERROR [scheduling-1] org.springframework.core.log.LogAccessor: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required to bind 2 arguments, but only bound 1 (JoinPointMatch was NOT bound in invocation), failedMessage=GenericMessage...
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultPollableMessageSource.doHandleMessage(DefaultPollableMessageSource.java:330)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultPollableMessageSource.handle(DefaultPollableMessageSource.java:361)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultPollableMessageSource.poll(DefaultPollableMessageSource.java:219)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultPollableMessageSource.poll(DefaultPollableMessageSource.java:200)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultPollableMessageSource.poll(DefaultPollableMessageSource.java:68)
    at xyx.pollForDeletionRequest(CleanupController.java:35)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required to bind 2 arguments, but only bound 1 (JoinPointMatch was NOT bound in invocation)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.argBinding(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:596)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:624)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:72)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692)
    at xyz.CleanupSubmissionServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8737f6f8.submitDeletion(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultPollableMessageSource.doHandleMessage(DefaultPollableMessageSource.java:327)
    ... 17 more
```

Comment: You don't need to provide your actual source code, an example which produces the problem is fine.

Comment: I've updated the description with an example to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please learn what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is and why your question is not one. You describe problems with two conflicting aspects, only posting one of them. That is counter-productive, because it leaves too much room for speculation and likely leads to iterations of comments back and forth, which is avoidable in this case. SO is not a discussion forum but a Q/A site. So the more precise you ask, the more precise the answer shall be. Help yourself by helping others reproducing your problem. _Dunny_ probably guessed right what you want here, but still he had to guess.

Comment: @kriegaex, thanks for the feedback. I've added in the aspect for `Log`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of [this problem](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/16956#issuecomment-822988103), you need to use `@Order(value = Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)` on `PollableStreamListenerAspect`. Quite weird indeed, but then it works as you wish it to. IMO the issue ought to be fixed in Spring, though. Having to use this workaround is ugly and only works if your aspect calling `proceed()` asynchronously actually does have the highest precedence, which is not always the case. As an alternative, you could use native AspectJ and its own concept of declaring advice precedence, which is independent of Spring internals.

Here is a simplified version of your application as an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

**Annotations:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q67155048;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CustomLogging {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q67155048;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface PollableStreamListener {}
```

**Component with method carrying both annotations:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q67155048;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyComponent {
  private int counter = 0;

  @PollableStreamListener
  @CustomLogging
  public void submitDeletion() {
    try {
      System.out.println("  Starting processing #" + ++counter);
      Thread.sleep(1000);
      System.out.println("  Finished processing #" + counter);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

**Aspects:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q67155048;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class CustomLoggingAspect {
  @Before("@annotation(de.scrum_master.spring.q67155048.CustomLogging)")
  public void addCustomLogging() {
    System.out.println("Logging");
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q67155048;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

@Aspect
@Component
@Order(value = Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class PollableStreamListenerAspect {
  public static final ExecutorService EXECUTOR_SERVICE = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
  private volatile boolean paused = false;

  @Around("@annotation(de.scrum_master.spring.q67155048.PollableStreamListener)")
  public void receiveMessage(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("Receiving message");
    if (!paused) {
      // The separate thread is not busy with a previous message, so process this message:
      Runnable runnable = () -> {
        try {
          paused = true;
          joinPoint.proceed();
        }
        catch (Throwable throwable) {
          throwable.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
          paused = false;
        }
      };
      EXECUTOR_SERVICE.submit(runnable);
    }
    else {
      System.out.println("  Re-queue");
    }
  }
}
```

**Driver application:**

The application calls the target method every 500 ms, but execution takes 1,000 ms. So we expect to see ~50% of the calls being re-queued without any logging in that case, because the higher precedence aspect does not proceed to the target method.

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q67155048;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
public class DemoApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    try (ConfigurableApplicationContext appContext = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args)) {
      doStuff(appContext);
    }
  }

  private static void doStuff(ConfigurableApplicationContext appContext) throws InterruptedException {
    MyComponent myComponent = appContext.getBean(MyComponent.class);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      myComponent.submitDeletion();
      Thread.sleep(500);
    }
    // This is just to make the application exit cleanly
    PollableStreamListenerAspect.EXECUTOR_SERVICE.shutdown();
  }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.8.RELEASE)

2021-04-20 12:56:03.675  INFO 13560 --- [           main] d.s.spring.q67155048.DemoApplication     : Starting DemoApplication on Xander-Ultrabook with PID 13560 (C:\Users\alexa\Documents\java-src\spring-aop-playground\target\classes started by alexa in C:\Users\alexa\Documents\java-src\spring-aop-playground)
...
2021-04-20 12:56:07.666  INFO 13560 --- [           main] d.s.spring.q67155048.DemoApplication     : Started DemoApplication in 4.65 seconds (JVM running for 7.181)
Receiving message
Logging
  Starting processing #1
Receiving message
  Re-queue
  Finished processing #1
Receiving message
Logging
  Starting processing #2
Receiving message
  Re-queue
  Finished processing #2
Receiving message
Logging
  Starting processing #3
Receiving message
  Re-queue
  Finished processing #3
Receiving message
Logging
  Starting processing #4
Receiving message
  Re-queue
  Finished processing #4
Receiving message
Logging
  Starting processing #5
Receiving message
  Re-queue
  Finished processing #5
2021-04-20 12:56:12.767  INFO 13560 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
...
```

See? We count 10x "Receiving message", but only 5x "Re-queue" and 5x "Logging". Please note that I numbered the processing calls because they are asynchronous. That way it is easier to follow when they start and finish.

---

**Update in response to user comment:**

I have updated my MCVE in order to reproduce your problem with the parameter binding. The new or changed files are:

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q67155048;

public class Message<T> {
  private T content;

  public Message(T content) {
    this.content = content;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Message{" +
      "content=" + content +
      '}';
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q67155048;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
public class DemoApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    try (ConfigurableApplicationContext appContext = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args)) {
      doStuff(appContext);
    }
  }

  private static void doStuff(ConfigurableApplicationContext appContext) throws InterruptedException {
    MyComponent myComponent = appContext.getBean(MyComponent.class);
    Message<String> message = new Message<>("Hi there!");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      myComponent.submitDeletion(message);
      Thread.sleep(500);
    }
    // This is just to make the application exit cleanly
    PollableStreamListenerAspect.EXECUTOR_SERVICE.shutdown();
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q67155048;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

@Aspect
@Component
@Order(value = Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class PollableStreamListenerAspect {
  public static final ExecutorService EXECUTOR_SERVICE = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
  private volatile boolean paused = false;

  @Around("@annotation(de.scrum_master.spring.q67155048.PollableStreamListener) && args(dataCapsule, ..)")
  public void receiveMessage(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, Object dataCapsule) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("Receiving message");
    if (!paused) {
      // The separate thread is not busy with a previous message, so process this message:
      Runnable runnable = () -> {
        try {
          paused = true;
          System.out.println("dataCapsule = " + dataCapsule);
          joinPoint.proceed();
        }
        catch (Throwable throwable) {
          throwable.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
          paused = false;
        }
      };
      EXECUTOR_SERVICE.submit(runnable);
    }
    else {
      System.out.println("  Re-queue");
    }
  }
}
```

This yields, according to your own experience:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required to bind 2 arguments, but only bound 1 (JoinPointMatch was NOT bound in invocation)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.argBinding(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:605)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at de.scrum_master.spring.q67155048.MyComponent$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4baa410d.submitDeletion(<generated>)
    at de.scrum_master.spring.q67155048.DemoApplication.doStuff(DemoApplication.java:21)
    at de.scrum_master.spring.q67155048.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:13)
```

You are hitting [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54286747/1082681), and I have commented on the closed [Spring issue #16956](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/16956#issuecomment-824536173) about it, hoping to get it repoened and someone to fix it.

For now, your workaround is not to use the elegant AOP argument binding but to fetch the parameter manually using `JoinPoint.getArgs()`:

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q67155048;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

@Aspect
@Component
@Order(value = Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class PollableStreamListenerAspect {
  public static final ExecutorService EXECUTOR_SERVICE = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
  private volatile boolean paused = false;

  //@Around("@annotation(de.scrum_master.spring.q67155048.PollableStreamListener) && args(dataCapsule, ..)")
  @Around("@annotation(de.scrum_master.spring.q67155048.PollableStreamListener) && execution(* *(*, ..))")
  //public void receiveMessage(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, Object dataCapsule) throws Throwable {
  public void receiveMessage(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    Object dataCapsule = joinPoint.getArgs()[0];
    System.out.println("Receiving message");
    if (!paused) {
      // The separate thread is not busy with a previous message, so process this message:
      Runnable runnable = () -> {
        try {
          paused = true;
          System.out.println("dataCapsule = " + dataCapsule);
          joinPoint.proceed();
        }
        catch (Throwable throwable) {
          throwable.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
          paused = false;
        }
      };
      EXECUTOR_SERVICE.submit(runnable);
    }
    else {
      System.out.println("  Re-queue");
    }
  }
}
```

Now it works again like this:

```
Receiving message
dataCapsule = Message{content=Hi there!}
Logging
  Starting processing #1, message = Message{content=Hi there!}
Receiving message
  Re-queue
Receiving message
  Re-queue
  Finished processing #1, message = Message{content=Hi there!}
Receiving message
dataCapsule = Message{content=Hi there!}
Logging
  Starting processing #2, message = Message{content=Hi there!}
Receiving message
  Re-queue
  Finished processing #2, message = Message{content=Hi there!}
Receiving message
dataCapsule = Message{content=Hi there!}
Logging
  Starting processing #3, message = Message{content=Hi there!}
Receiving message
  Re-queue
  Finished processing #3, message = Message{content=Hi there!}
Receiving message
dataCapsule = Message{content=Hi there!}
Logging
  Starting processing #4, message = Message{content=Hi there!}
Receiving message
  Re-queue
  Finished processing #4, message = Message{content=Hi there!}
Receiving message
dataCapsule = Message{content=Hi there!}
Logging
  Starting processing #5, message = Message{content=Hi there!}
```

Comment: I've given your sample code a try. It works for me if I don't care about the Kafka message. But if I try to add the Kafka message as a param to the joinpoint (if that's the right word to use here?) then I get an exception. I've updated the description above with some details.

Any ideas?

Thanks again for your help

Comment: I updated my answer in response to your follow-up question yesterday, but forgot to notify you. Please take a look, then accept + upvote the answer. I think I did more than enough to answer your questions (plural), even the modified one after you updated your original one.

Comment: Yes, I saw that you updated your response. Thanks. I've been busy with other things today, but will try out your updated sample soon.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but I've finally used your suggested approach in my app and it's working. I've accepted and upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `@Order` annotation on the two aspects to define the ordering. If it's not provided, the execution order of aspects is undefined.
For example, if the Log aspect should always be executed as the last advice, no matter what other advices there are, give it e.g. an order of 10000, and all other advices lower numbers (lower numbers are executed first).

Documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-ordering

Comment: Thanks for your response. Does using `@Order` work if we sometimes want the `@Log` aspect not to run at all?

Comment: From my understanding yes, if you don't call `joinPoint.proceed();` in an advice, all following advices will not be executed as well as the method itself. It will not work however, if you just don't want to execute the Log advice, but still want to call the underlying method or other advices following. Then you would need to add some logic to the Log advice itself to determine, if you want to create a log statement.

Comment: I've given this a try, but it's throwing an exception. From my research I think this is because the logic inside the method annotated with `@Annotation1` executes inside another thread (I'll update the description in a moment with that info. I didn't think it was relevant, but can now see that it might be). Another stackoverflow post explains that for a method to execute in another thread, we need to make sure that it has the highest order value, but in my case we want the lowest value - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147031/spring-aspect-fails-when-join-point-is-invoked-in-new-thread

Comment: Exception:

No MethodInvocation found: Check that an AOP invocation is in progress and that the ExposeInvocationInterceptor is upfront in the interceptor chain. Specifically, note that advices with order HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE will execute before ExposeInvocationInterceptor! In addition, ExposeInvocationInterceptor and ExposeInvocationInterceptor.currentInvocation() must be invoked from the same thread.
...

Comment: Please edit the question and just leave a short comment about the update, rather than posting exceptions and other technical information as unformatted comments. IMO your situation is too complex to deal with by just posting an incoherent set of code snippets which **you** think are relevant. You don't know the answer to your question, so you have no way of knowing what causes it. Please condense the problem into an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post it on GitHub. I need to reproduce it, then probably I can help you. I dislike guessing and speculating.

Comment: I've updated the description with more info to help reproduce the problem, and an extra note about the `@Order`. I'm not sure of the reason, but this time when I tried `@Order` it doesn't give an exception but instead fails to receive messages at all.

Before posting on GitHub I'd like to hear your thoughts now that I've provided some more info about the problem.